# Struts2: global-results configuration error

Tags: java, struts2

I want to use a global result "login". But it ony works without global-results in the configuration. This is the relevant part of my configuration:

categoryList.jsp
   categoryDetail.jsp
  
  
   /WEB-INF/login.jsp

When I start my application it throws this Exception:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "package" must match     "(result-types?,interceptors?,default-interceptor-ref?,default-action-ref?,default-class-ref?,global-results?,global-exception-mappings?,action*)".

What is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it! The order matters.

**Order** in struts.xml matters:

1. result-types?
2. interceptors?
3. default-interceptor-ref?
4. default-action-  ref?
5. default-class-ref?
6. global-results?
7. global-exception-mappings?
8. action*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the tags must be in order : result-types -> interceptors -> default-interceptor-ref -> default-action-ref -> default-class-ref -> global-results -> global-exception-mappings -> action*