# When i write default action in my struts.xml an error is occured in struts

Tags: struts2, struts2-interceptors

This is my code

**struts.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
            "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN"
            "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">

         <!-- ********************************************************** -->   

        <struts>

         <!-- ********************************************************** -->

            <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
            <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

         <!-- ********************************************************** -->

            <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

        <!-- *****************DEFAULT ACTION STARTS********************* -->        
                <default-action-ref name="somedefault" />

                <!-- ******************************* --> 

                <action name="somedefault">
                <result>/jsp/DefaultPage.jsp</result>
                </action>


        <!-- *****************DEFAULT ACTION ENDS********************* -->      

        <!-- *****************GLOBAL RESULTS STARTS********************* -->

                <global-results>

                      <result name="null">/jsp/Fail1.jsp</result>
                      <result name="excep">/jsp/Fail2.jsp</result>

                </global-results>

        <!-- ******************GLOBAL RESULTS ENDS********************** -->        

        <!-- *************GLOBAL EXCEPTION MAPPING STARTS*************** -->    

                <global-exception-mappings>

                      <exception-mapping result="null" exception="java.lang.NullPointerException" />              
                      <exception-mapping result="excep" exception="java.lang.Exception" />

                </global-exception-mappings>

        <!-- **************GLOBAL EXCEPTION MAPPING ENDS***************** -->   

        <!-- ******************OTHER ACTION STARTS*********************** -->

                <action name="Calculator" class="com.action.Calculator">

                    <exception-mapping result="error" exception="java.lang.NumberFormatException" />
                    <exception-mapping result="none" exception="java.lang.NullPointerException" />       

                <result name="success">/jsp/Success.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">/jsp/Error.jsp</result>
                <result name="none">/jsp/Error1.jsp</result>

            </action>

                <!-- ************************************ -->       

                <action name="Action1" class="com.action.Action1">

                <result name="success">/jsp/Success1.jsp</result>

            </action>

                <!-- ************************************ -->

            <action name="Action2" class="com.action.Action2">

                <result name="success">/jsp/Success1.jsp</result>

            </action>       

        <!-- *********************OTHER ACTION ENDS********************** -->   

            </package>

        <!-- ************************************************************ -->   

        </struts>
```

I dont know whts happening an error 
the error  shows
The content of element type "package" must match "(result-types?,interceptors?,default-interceptor-ref?,default-action-ref?,default-class-ref?,global-results?,global-
 exception-mappings?,action*)".
Please correct me

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3742379/1700321.

Comment: I follow that order sir you check it

Comment: How Sir?Please help me

Comment: You starts with default-action-ref, that should be near the end... seriously, just check the order in the other Q&A :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the definition of your default action to the section of the spec where the other actions are defined.  I've removed the comments and reindented so that you can see the XML elements more clearly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <default-action-ref name="somedefault" />
        <global-results>
            <result name="null">/jsp/Fail1.jsp</result>
            <result name="excep">/jsp/Fail2.jsp</result>
        </global-results>
        <global-exception-mappings>
            <exception-mapping result="null" exception="java.lang.NullPointerException" />          
            <exception-mapping result="excep" exception="java.lang.Exception" />
        </global-exception-mappings>
        <action name="somedefault">
            <result>/jsp/DefaultPage.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Calculator" class="com.action.Calculator">
            <exception-mapping result="error" exception="java.lang.NumberFormatException" />
            <exception-mapping result="none" exception="java.lang.NullPointerException" />       
            <result name="success">/jsp/Success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/jsp/Error.jsp</result>
            <result name="none">/jsp/Error1.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Action1" class="com.action.Action1">
            <result name="success">/jsp/Success1.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Action2" class="com.action.Action2">
            <result name="success">/jsp/Success1.jsp</result>
        </action>       
    </package>
</struts>
```